# R shiny / javascript widget for drawing connections between matching column name pairs?

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I am building a Shiny App that, among others, allow users to merge two files. I would like to allow the users to dynamically select the columns for matching. More precisely, I am searching for a widget that would allow the user to draw 1-1 connection(s) between matching column names that should be used for merging.

For example, if table1 has the columns "username", "id", "score" and table2 "num_id", "game time" "pseudo", the user could draw connections like in the picture here below, that could then be retrieve server-side to use `by.x =c("username", "id"), by.y=c("pseudo", "num_id")` in the merging function.

Are you aware of a R package or a JS library that would allow to do that ??

I was thinking at something in the same vein as a drag and drop and found the R package [sortable](https://rstudio.github.io/sortable) but from what I  understand it does not really allow to do what I am looking for. I've spent quite some time googling but did not find anything that meets my needs... So if you have any suggestions, they are welcome :-)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a ready-made solution for this. I suggest sticking to established user input types. That way your app will work for users on mobile and desktop alike and it'll be less confusing to operate.

You could use existing `shiny` inputs and dynamically compose them. [Mastering Shiny](https://mastering-shiny.org/action-dynamic.html) has a chapter on that topic.

Here are two ideas that might get you started.

### Option A `sortable`:

1. Show one bucket with variable names.
2. Show second bucket, instruct user to drag one variable name from each dataset.
3. When second bucket contains two variables, add a third bucket for the next connection between variables.
4. Repeat 3 whenever the last bucket contains 2 var names.

This could be achieved with `shiny::observeEvent()`, `sortable::update_rank_list()`, and `sortable::update_bucket_list()`. You'd also want to add in some checks that make sure that there are no more than two var names in the connection buckets and that they are not from the same dataset. Whenever an *illegal* configuration appears reset to the previous state and display a message informing the user of what they did wrong.

#### Option B `shiny::selectInput()`:

1. Show two `selectInput()` fields next to each other, one for each set of variable names.
2. Prompt the user to select variable names to connect.
3. After they select a variable name from each input add another row of `selectInput()` fields.
4. Repeat 3. whenever the user selects a pair of variable names.

You'd probably want to add a delete/reset button to each pair so the user can get rid of selections they made in error. This could be implemented with `shiny::uiOutput()` and `shiny::renderUI()`.